# TouchPad becomes unresponsive exactly before installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, touchpad

I am using IdeaPad Flex 5 14ALC7 comes with AMD 5500 processor and windows 11 . I tried to dual boot with ubuntu 22.04 LTS version and used rufus to create a bootable pendrive and when I booted from the pen drive a welcome screen opened asking to try or install ubuntu .
From here the touchpad become unresponsive and as I can not move the cursor I could not move further .

One More Question :: there is a list of devices which is supported by ubuntu at the official website of ubuntu and this machine is not in that list . Could It also be problematic even if I will be able to install ??

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This might be a bug on a version of kernel. You can 1) use a USB mouse to do this job for now, 2) Install 20.04 or 21.10, then upgrade to 22.04. [Ubuntu cert laptops](https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops). It depends on the peripherals come with the main board, for example, touch screens and auto-rotational display are problematic than a standard computer.